# POS Community rewards scam

Tags: scam

[image]

I was in a staking project and my USDT was transfered to an « Event ».
If I do not complete with 4x more USDT in 5 days my founds will be permanently frozen.

According to you, Is this a scam ?
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Currently the reward for staking in Ethereum is around 5.8% apr, see https://beaconcha.in/ethstore. Anything that pays more than that is at least doubtful. If they don't provide more details about how the earning are estimated, or details for you to validate then it is likely a scam.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an ask, it is 99% likely a scam.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/89387)

Comment: That's the rule of the thumb here. People can here only to ask scams if they are actual scams or they have been already scammed. Telling them it's not a scam or maybe a scam is not helpful. During my 6 years here I have not seen a single question that would have not turned out not to be a scam.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was a scam. This is painful to see, my heart hurts honestly. I am in the same position. I was in the same exact one for 12.88 and lost 40k which was my standard. Now they want me to pay 37% taxes or they wont release my money. I have contacted crypto lawyers but they want 4k-8k for an investigation just to turn it over to authorities. How did you learn about this project as well?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).